# React way to open a NavBar onClick on a button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I trying to find a way to open the navbar of ReactJS app when i'm clicking on my "`MENU`" button.

At the beginning my nav component have a `width` of `0px` (with `overflow : hidden`). When i'm clicking on the button my nav should have a `width` of `400px`. I'm a beginner with React.

I have two React Components :

1. `Topbar`

```js
export default function Topbar() {
    return (
        <div className="topbar__container">
            <div className='topbar__menuButton'>
                <Link className="topbar__link">MENU</Link>
            </div>
            <div className="topbar__title">
                <Link to="/" className="topbar__link">EDGAR</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

2. `Nav`

```js
const Nav = () => {
    return (
        <div className="navbar__container">
                <Query query={CATEGORIES_QUERY} id={null}>
                    {({ data: { categories } }) => {
                        return (
                            <nav className="nav">
                                <ul>
                                    {categories.map((category, i) => {
                                        return (
                                            <li key={category.id}>
                                                <Link to={`/category/${category.id}`} className="nav__link">
                                                    {category.name}
                                                </Link>
                                            </li>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        )
                    }}
                </Query>
            </div>
    )
}

export default Nav
```

Comment: why did you wrap the Menu in <Link> ?

Comment: why not use the pre-built and tested bootstrap react library which takes care of a lot of the process that happens under the hood which you are trying to do now. DRY

Comment: @Asking i was trying something else, I just forgot to change this

Comment: @Saravanan i wanted to create something more personnal than just using a bootstrap element. I just want to learn something new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve something like that you have to set this logic in the common parent of both component (here `App` for the example).

`App` will manage a state to determine if the `Nav` is open or not. The state is called `isMenuOpen` and can be changed using the `setIsMenuOpen()` function. We will give to the children `Nav` the state `isMenuOpen` and to the children `TopBar` a callback from the function `setIsMenuOpen()`:

*App.jsx*

```js
import React from "react";

import TopBar from "./TopBar";
import Nav from "./Nav";

export default function App() {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TopBar setMenuStatus={setIsMenuOpen} />
      <Nav isOpen={isMenuOpen} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then the `TopBar` have to set the value of `isMenuOpen` to `true` using the function `setIsMenuOpen()` from the props.

*TopBar.jsx*

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Topbar({ setMenuStatus }) {
  return (
    <div className="topbar__container">
      <div className="topbar__menuButton">
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            setMenuStatus(true);
          }}
        >
          Menu
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then the component `Nav` will set a specific class (here `.open`) if `isOpen` coming from props is `true`.

*Nav.jsx*

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Nav({ isOpen }) {
  return (
    <div id="nav" className={isOpen ? "open" : ""}>
      Menu
    </div>
  );
}
```

*styles.css*

```css
#nav {
  display: none;
}

#nav.open {
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can try this example in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-hermann-ll3t3?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: This actually is a nicer approach.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle]= React.useState(false)
  const [width, setWidth]= React.useState('')

  const showMenu = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle)
    if(toggle === true) {
      setWidth('50px')
    }else {
      setWidth('500px')
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={showMenu}>Menu</button>
      <div style={{width, border:'1px solid red'}}>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

reproducing link: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-flower-rxdk3?file=/src/App.js:0-592

Comment: @Théo Vogel, please, let me know if my example helped you.