# Create navbar using React and Bootstrap

Tags: react-bootstrap

The navbar that I'm creating has its brand showing, however the links will not appear. The toggle button appears when shrinking the screen, but still no links appear when I click the button.

```
import React from "react";

function Navbar()
{
return(
<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" >Demo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
      data-target="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
     navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse nabar-collapse" id="navbarText">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu<span class="sr-only"> 
              (current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
      </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
);
 }
export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Check out the react documentation on handling clicks. If you do have a click handler in your function please update your example code to include it. It also looks like you're asking something that has been answered before; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175474/react-way-to-open-a-navbar-onclick-on-a-button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React way to open a NavBar onClick on a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175474/react-way-to-open-a-navbar-onclick-on-a-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I was missing a "v", insert facepalm.